Camera is not detecting chessboard corners using Python and OpenCV
My code looks like this:
def find_corners(images, camera_name):
    imgpoints = []
    for idx, img in enumerate(images):
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Find the chessboard corners
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, grid_size, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
        if ret:
            objpoints.append(objp)
            # Refine the corner locations to subpixel accuracy
            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

            # Draw and display the corners
            cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, grid_size, corners2, ret)
            cv2.imshow(f'{camera_name} Image {idx + 1}', img)

            # Wait for a keypress to move to the next image
            print(f"Displaying {camera_name} Image {idx + 1}. Press any key to continue...")
            cv2.waitKey(0)  # Wait until a key is pressed
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        else:
            print(f"Chessboard not found in {camera_name} Image {idx + 1}")
    return imgpoints

Grid size:
grid_size = (14, 14)  # Inner corners of the chessboard

I have two cameras. One camera3 detects corners just fine, it returns points. The camera2 corner detection does not find any points. Both images were generated using Solidworks and both are pretty much identical except for perspective.
This image calibrated fine:

This image does not:

The order that I try them does not matter. I have re-rendered and resaved the "bad" image and it still does not calibrate.

Please fix the indentation and also where is grid_size

Where does it fail What error message do your get? What are your criteria values?  Can you provide the imports and file reads and main code and the zipped original files so that we can try your code?

I added code to make the image a binary image (either white or black pixels. That resolved the issue. Thanks.

those pics have transparent background. make sure it's white or whatever. the algorithms assume to be seeing a checkerboard printed on paper, i.e. white border. "quiet zone" and all that jazz.

Use different vorizontal and vertical gird size.

that's a good idea but that is not the reason for the failing detection.
